# exe from a most simple tkinter python script not working

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

Here is my code of a very simple python script using tkinter. I am trying to convert into an exe file to run on my windows 10 laptop but the exe is not working properly.

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
def myfunc():
    t1.delete("1.0", "end")
    t2.delete("1.0", "end")
    t3.delete("1.0", "end")
    kg = float(mytext.get())
    gm = kg*1000
    t1.insert(END, gm)
    pound = kg*2.2
    t2.insert(END, pound)
    ounce = kg*35.2
    t3.insert(END, ounce)
mytext = StringVar()
e1 = Entry(window, textvariable=mytext)
e1.grid(row=1, column=1)
b1 = Button(window, text='Convert', command=myfunc)
b1.grid(row=1, column=3)
t1 = Text(window, height=1, width=20)
t1.grid(row=2, column=1)
t2 = Text(window, height=1, width=20)
t2.grid(row=2, column=2)
t3 = Text(window, height=1, width=20)
t3.grid(row=2, column=3)
window.mainloop()
```

I have already installed pyinstaller using pip.
I run pyinstaller.exe --onefile .\kgconverter.py it creates a dist folder and inside it an exe file.
when I double click on this exe file, nothing happens a black window opens for a fraction of second and goes away.

[image]

any help? I am clueless what's wrong going on?

Comment: Seems like a graphics issue, I can run the same code just fine on Linux. Try to check if the graphics libraries are correctly collected into the .exe

Comment: which graphic libraries? help plz

Comment: I have tried your code on windows 10 and changed to .exe and it just works fine are you sure that pyinstaller is installed with no problems? try installing it again if not from pip.